# Hide button with tag from another view class not working.

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uibutton

i am newbie in iOS. i make an app that contain Scrollview and in Scrollview i added 10 Page each page contain 12 button and set one stop button outside of my Scrollview here i want to set when stop button pressed then i want to hide my selected button but it was not working but when i was click on same button in the view then it is hide but here i want to hide selected button when stop button was clicked here i write code like as

```
-(void)clikedOnButton:(UIButton*)whichButtonClicked
{
  SaveSoundIntoArray *saveInfointoArray=[SaveSoundIntoArray sharedInstance];
  if(whichButtonClicked.selected)
   {
    NSLog(@"button selected is:%@",whichButtonClicked);
    NSUInteger butTag=(long)whichButtonClicked.tag;
    NSLog(@"button clicked is:%ld",butTag);
    switch (butTag)
    {
        case 1:
        {
            [[self.view viewWithTag:2] setHidden:YES];
            [[self.view viewWithTag:121] setHidden:YES];
            [saveInfointoArray.stopAllPlayer removeObject:saveInfointoArray.player1];  //when unselect the button ,remove object from array
            [saveInfointoArray.saveButtonName removeObject:whichButtonClicked]; //when unselect object button remove object from array
            [saveInfointoArray.selectedButtonButNotMoreThanTen removeObject:whichButtonClicked];
            [saveInfointoArray.VolumeSaveForPlayer removeObjectForKey:@"1"];
            totalSelectedButtonButNotMoreThanTen=[SaveSoundIntoArray countTotalSelectedButton:-1 and:1 and:0];
            whichButtonClicked.selected =NO;
            [saveInfointoArray.player1 stop];  //tap=2 , player1 stop
        }
            break;
  }
 }
```

This method in my view1 now i call this method when stop button pressed like as

```
- (IBAction)stopAllPlayers:(id)sender
{
view1=[[View1 alloc]init];
SaveSoundIntoArray *saveInfointoArray=[SaveSoundIntoArray sharedInstance];
if(saveInfointoArray.stopAllPlayer.count == 0)
 {
 UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Selection Empty" message:@"Your Selection is Empty" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
 [alert show];
 }
else
{
for(int i=0;i<saveInfointoArray.stopAllPlayer.count;i++)
{
    copyOfSaveButtonName[i]=saveInfointoArray.saveButtonName[i];    //copy bcz loop mathi method call kriye tyare remove object thay 6
    copyOfStopAllPlayer[i]=saveInfointoArray.stopAllPlayer[i];  //copy bcz stopallplayer removeObject
    copyOfSaveButtonTag[i]=saveInfointoArray.saveButtonTag[i];  //copy bcz savebuttonTag removeObject
}
for(int i=0;i<copyOfStopAllPlayer.count;i++) //error here
{
    NSLog(@"button:%@ and Player:%@ is STOP",copyOfSaveButtonName[i],copyOfStopAllPlayer[i]);
    NSLog(@"button Tag is:%@",copyOfSaveButtonName[i]);
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    button=copyOfSaveButtonName[i];
    button.selected=YES;
    NSLog(@"tag is :%@",copyOfSaveButtonTag[i]);
    int currentTag=[copyOfSaveButtonTag[i] intValue]; //use buttonTag for comparison of buttontags
    NSLog(@"currentTag: %d",currentTag);
    if(currentTag>=1 && currentTag<=12)
    {
    [view1 clikedOnButton:button];
    }
  }
```

Here i not get tag of button from stop button it is i not know because i confuse about it please help me

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can use:

```
UIButton *clickedButton = (UIButton*)sender;
NSLog(@"tag is : %i", clickedButton.tag)
```

Comment: where i use it can you help me?

Comment: i assume that your "copyOfStopAllPlayer" - array contains the correct objects because i don't know the stuff that happens in your  "SaveSoundIntoArray" class (if not you should init the "copyOfStopAllPlayer"array  before using) - than you can use the "UIButton *clickedButton = (UIButton*)sender;" while iterating the "copyOfStopAllPlayer" array,  int currentTag = clickedButton.tag ...